# SSIS Converting CSV to Text file changes Date format

Tags: csv, ssis

I have a .CSV file that is taking information from my database and has a bunch of dates in the following format: `6/1/2016 0:00`

I'm not sure if this matters but for the Flat File Destination Input, the External Columns have it as a data type of "[DT_DBDATE]" while the Input Columns show it as "DT_DBTIMESTAMP"

The problem is, when I add a file system task to convert this file into a .TXT file, it changes the date format to:

```
2016-06-01 00:00:00
```

How can I prevent this from happening and keep the original format from the CSV?

Comment: Unless your final destination is an American human, the 2016-06-01 00:00:00 format is preferable as the is no ambiguity

Comment: It's not preferable in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify some things: 1. A date stored in a database using a date data type has no format. 2. Make sure you're looking at your TXT file in a text editor, not excel. In both cases it's the 'client tool' that imposes a format. Note that your current output format is pretty close to the `ISO` format, which is as close to a standard date format that we'll ever get. If everyone just stuck to the ISO format we'd probably see a 50% improvement in development efficiency as all these frustrating date issues would disappear. Is the TXT file for consumption by a human or a computer?

Answer (score 0):

Add a SSIS Derived column and use the following expression

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",COLUMNNAME),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",COLUMNNAME),2) + "/" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yy",COLUMNNAME)
```

**IMP:** Replace COLUMNNAME with the column name in your input file

Now you can map this column to the date column in the output file.